# Automatically infer type for forwardRef Element with react-typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I am wrapping several components and I need to use forwardRef in my case similar to this example:

```
import { forwardRef, ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children?: ReactNode;
  type: "submit" | "button";
}
export type Ref = HTMLButtonElement;

export const FancyButton = forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="MyClassName" type={props.type}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

To extract the boilerplate and auto generate it via a code generator CLI tool. I want to automate the typing of the passed through component. For that case I want to use a custom utility to infer the HTML element of the component e.g. if I am wrapping a button I want the Utility to infer HTMLButtonElement. Should be same process like this example

```
export type $ElementProps<T> = T extends React.ComponentType<infer Props>
  ? Props extends object
    ? Props
    : never
  : never;
```

but I have no idea how to infer the Element Type if that is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { forwardRef, ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
    children?: ReactNode;
    type: "submit" | "button";
}
export type Ref = HTMLButtonElement;

export const FancyButton = forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => (
    <button ref={ref} className="MyClassName" type={props.type}>
        {props.children}
    </button>
));


type $ElementProps<T> =
    (T extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<infer Ref>
        ? (Ref extends React.RefAttributes<infer RefElement>
            ? RefElement
            : never
        )
        : never
    )

type RefElement = $ElementProps<typeof FancyButton> // HTMLButtonElement
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-UhA1BWaHSeT3TTpCMqR7afSrVCIPg4D0+gMKtFFkA)